# Jinja2 Import Static HTML in Pyramid

Tags: python, templates, pyramid, jinja2

My application contains Angular code.  I want Jinja2 templating within the layout, but need to be able to use Angular expressions within the page.  I'd like to do that by importing a static HTML file into the main Jinja2 template that is *not parsed*.

How can I import an HTML template file without parsing it?  A Jinja2 extension?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "import", do you mean copying it in by hand, or do you mean you have some HTML in another file that you'd like injected (unparsed) somewhere within the template?

If it's the latter you're after -- including an HTML file without parsing -- you could write an extension, sure, but it's far simpler to just put the file's contents into a context variable (named, say, `rawHtml`) and output it like so:

```
{{ rawHtml }}
```

On the other hand, if you're writing the HTML inside the template itself and you want it rendered without interpretation, you can accomplish that too by using the [`raw` construct](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#escaping):

```
{% raw %}
    <a href="#">He had a great moustache, like this :-{ </a>
{% endraw %}
```

Comment: The former is what I'm looking for.  How would I import the file into the variable?  I'm not sure how to render a file by itself.

Comment: @Jonah: Read the file into a variable in Python (`with open('foo.htm', 'rb') as f: rawHtml = f.read().decode('utf-8-sig')`). Then inject that into the context: `template.render({ 'rawHtml': rawHtml })`.

Comment: it seems messy to be working directly with the IO library.  Pyramid doesn't have a simple way to pull in a template file?  How would I handle the path to the templates directory that way?

Comment: @Jonah: Ah, sorry, I don't know Pyramid. I assumed you were rendering the templates yourself (in which case you control the template search path, etc.), but it seems that's not the case. Anyway, I agree that an extension would be cleaner -- I'll try to find the time to write one that does this. I'll post it here if I do.